# Modify simple list/array in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, interpolation, terraform

I have a next list:

```
azs = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"]
```

And I am using it during subnets creation. In names of subnets I would like to use short names like `a, b, c` so I need a list `["a", "b", "c"]`. Obviously I need to generate it dynamically (in locals block for example) when `azs` will be set manually.

How to create such list with Terraform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`formatlist`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#formatlist-format-args-) function here to format a list.

It uses the string format syntax, taking *n* lists and returning a single list.

So in your case you probably want something like:

```
locals {
  azs = [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
  ]
}

output "azs" {
  value = "${formatlist("us-east-1%s", local.azs)}"
}
```

Comment: I would like to get ["a", "b", "c"] list from ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"] list, not vise versa.

Comment: Why are you going that way round? Can you maybe expand your question to show what you're trying to do more fully?

Comment: Previously I've thought to create new `[a, b, c]` list from `["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"]` with `[:-1]` as in Python. But your variant looks OK too given that TF language is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of for and the regex function to manipulate the items in your list.

```
locals {
    azs = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"]
}

output "azsList" {
    value = [for v in local.azs : regex("us-east-1([a-z])", v)]
}

output "azsMap" {
    value = {for v in local.azs : v => regex("us-east-1([a-z])", v)}
}

...

resource "example" "example"{
  dynamic "setting_section_name" {
    for_each = [for v in local.azs : regex("us-east-1([a-z])", v)]
    content {
      value = setting_section_name.value
    }
  }
}
```

You can change out the regex pattern to whatever you want.

Here are some helpful links:

[Terraform Regex](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/regex) Reference

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/) an online regex tool